# jquery animation in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-animate, jsfiddle

I've made an animation for my site logo, code works fine in jsfiddle, but when I upload it to wordpress one of my functions (animation) seems not be working (picture not moving left and top), while other (rotation) works fine. Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/5nwdjbp6/

```
(function rotation() {


$({deg: 325}).animate({deg: 345}, {
    duration: 1200,
    step: function(now){
        $('.random').css({
             transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
        });
    }
}).animate({deg: 325}, $.extend(true, {}, {
    duration: 2000,
    step: function(now){
        $('.random').css({
             transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
            });
        }}, {
        complete: function() {
           rotation();
        }
     })
 );
})();




(function animation() {

   $('.random').animate({
            left: "130px",
            top: "105px",
         },
         {
        duration: 1200,

   }
      )
      .animate({
            left: "90px",
          top: "90px",
         },
         $.extend(true, {}, {
      duration: 2000,

      }, {
        complete: function() {
           animation();
        }
     })
  );
})();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the CSS styles are the same? Especially the position.

Comment: position is relative in wp and that div is also placed in bootstrap column. tried to change position to absolute - didn't work

Answer (score 0):

`"position is relative in wp and that div is also placed in bootstrap column"` - that's the problem. You can't use `top` and `left` for relatively positioned elements, but `margin-top` and `margin-left` instead. When you switch that, it should work exactly the same as in the fiddle.

Comment: changed top and left to marginTop and marginLeft, still not working... also tried to change position to absolute but no luck

Comment: That's the only error I could see from your code. Not sure anyone will able to help you more without seeing it live.

Comment: thanks anyway... actually it looks even better with rotation only :D

Comment: Haha, no problem! :)  If you want me to take a look at it when it goes live, just write a link here.